# How to make wchar_t 16 bit with clang for linux-x64?

Tags: 64-bit, clang, wchar-t

I cannot make clang on 64 bit linux to compile wchar_t to 16 bit

```
printf("%i ", sizeof (wchar_t));
```

prints `4`

```
clang++ -fshort-char test.cpp
```

although I use -fshort-char

my question is how to make wchar_t to 16 bit. is `#define` the only option?

```
#define wchar_t unsigned short
```

Comment: You cannot `#define wchar_t`. It is generally undefined behavior and in this particular case will guarantee that none of the standard wide string functions (that are already compiled and would not be aware of the change) work. If you are going to write your own functions, and that may be your only recourse, don't call your wide char type `wchar_t` (the `_t` suffix is reserved by POSIX anyway).

Comment: By the same token, you shouldn't print the result of `sizeof` with `%i`. Use `%zu` if your compiler supports it, or `printf("%u ", (unsigned int) sizeof (wchar_t));`

Comment: Why does `wchar_t` have to be 16 bits for you?

Comment: @MikeKinghan, because 16 bits is very convenient to handle all common languages. Why double stretch every type out there? They could stretch boolean to 64 bits as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to make `wchar_t` be 16 bits with clang (or gcc) is to
pass the compiler option `-fshort-wchar` (not `-fshort-char`).

This is a rather drastic measure, however, as it may break code that
calls the Standard Library or 3rd party libraries passing `wchar_t` data. Note 
that by default `wchar_t` is 32 bits for gcc and clang regardless of whether the
compiler targets 32-bit or 64-bit systems. In this respect they
conform with the C Standard 7.17/2 which requires `wchar_t` to be:

> an integer type whose range of values can represent distinct codes for all
>   members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales

As you are invoking `clang++` I presume you are compiling C++ source.
If you simply require a character type that is 16 bits wide, and can compile
with the option `-std=c++11`, the core language offers you `char16_t`, which
is suitable for storing any UTF-16 character. (And should you wish to
be able to store any UTF-32 character, `char32_t` will do).

Comment: Note that Unicode requires a minimum of 21-bits to represent the the initial standardized code points, and this would mean that a 16-bit wchar_t could never be used to represent Unicode code points. On GNU/Linux the standard ABI for wchar_t is a 32-bit type which is more than enough to represent all the current Unicode code points and could even be implemented directly as UTF-8 internally.